# What packages do I need to import if I would like to run a ntruencrypt source code in Java?

Tags: encryption, hash, elliptic-curves

What packages do I need to import if I would like to run a ntruencrypt source code in Java?

Comment: Generally you'd just put the .jar file in the build (class) path.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I managed to create a project file and then added .jar file